# How to use angular-filter

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use group by. For this purpose I included and referenced angular-filter.js. I am trying to use the filter but I am getting: Unknown provider: angular.filterProvider <- angular.filter. Am I referencing the filter correctly in the controller?

**View**

```
<md-list ng-repeat="(key, value) in Items| groupBy: '[subjectName,topicName]'"><md-list>
```

**Controller**

```
myModule.controller('testController', 
       ['angular.filter', function ($scope, $routeParams, $filter, adminService) {
)]};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the angular-filter.js as a dependency of your module:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller dependency injection should be like below. See how to do  [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) in angularjs

```
myModule.controller('testController', 
   ['$scope','$routeParams','$filter','adminService', function ($scope, $routeParams, $filter, adminService) {}]);
```